# Tmux use bright colors?

Tags: tmux, colors, iterm

I'm using iTerm and I was wondering if it was possible to use the "bright" colors in the Tmux config file. I googled this and I seen something that did `fg=cyan,bg=black,bright` and when I tried this, it didn't work. I know the regular colors are working as well as 256 colors are working and I am reloading the source file every time I change the color (this is how I know 256 colors and my regular palette is working because they change upon reloading the source).

Comment: By "source file" do you mean a Tmux config file or iTerm config file?  What is the path to the file you're changing (and how are you reloading it)?

Comment: @Wildcard Yes, I mean the tmux config. I reload it with `tmux source-file .tmux.conf`. As said before, color switching works for all the normal colors in my terminals set color palette. Though I'm trying to use the second black color. If you look at the website http://terminal.sexy I'm trying to get it to use the "second" black (8th position).

Answer (score 1):

## Use terminal colors *(including the prefix bright)*

Although the current suggestion to use HEX colours will work, it won't fetch the colours from your terminal.

To use colors from 8-15 **name the colors using the prefix bright**, like so:

```
# Colors 8-15 
brightblack
brightred
brightgreen
brightyellow
brightblue
brightmagenta 
brightcyan
brightwhite
```

[I've also seen bright](https://arcolinux.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-tmux-status-bar/) included after the color, such as:

```
fg=green,bright,bold
```

**But this has not worked for me** (tmux 3.1a)

Answer (score 0):

## Use HEX colors

### Example ~/.tmux.conf

```bsh
BACKGROUND="#000000"
BLUE="#569CD6"

set -g status-style bg=$BACKGROUND,fg=$BLUE
set -g window-status-current-format "#[fg=$BLUE] ➤ "
```